# Не выводятся сообщения UIAlertController

Tags: objective-c

Создаю новый проект, без каких либо манипуляций сразу в файл `ViewController.m`

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert" message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Никакой `alert` из этого дела не выходит, в консоль приходит сообщение:

> 2015-11-01 19:32:48.938 exp111[1212:625337] Warning: Attempt to present on whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Кто и что может сказать по этому поводу?
ЗЫ: Гуглением ничего хорошего не нарыл

Comment: Вы случайно не во viewDidLoad вызываете UIAlertController??

Comment: Да, в этом проекте в нём. В другом, после чего и возник вопрос, из отдельного метода. Хотя, этот так же вызывался и viewDidLoad, поэтому тоже самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в методе `viewDidLoad` еще не произошла загрузка непосредственно самого view, и вы пытаетесь положить сверху еще не созданного `view` - `allertView`. Вынесете это в метод  `viewDidAppear:` и все должно заработать.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Сделал в ViewDidiLoad флаг и по его значению вывожу в viewDidAppear сообщение. Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @GeorgiiBaruchyan всегда пожалуйтса)))